# Sort multiple rows into one line while combining fields

Tags: vba

Please see a basic example of what I'm trying to achieve in the photo, table 2 shows what i am trying to achieve from table 1. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

EDITED: As the previous explanation was vague, I have added an image of the actual table and re-written the question below.

[ACTUAL TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okajN.png)

I need a macro that will run through the cutting list shown and condense the data.

If "L", "W", "T", "Material", "Face Veneers" and "Edge Veneers/Lippings" have the same entry then they require combining. The cutting lists will always vary in quantity of rows depending on the job size.

I need the quantity ("QTY") totalled for the amount of parts combined and the "Part Code" combined so the workshop can label each part during the cutting process.

There will be rows mixed within the total that have individual data, so will not need combining.

The left over rows after being combined will require deleting.

I hope this is clearer! Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help section on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question, as this will help the community better understand your specific issue and provide you with a good answer.  Specifically, we need to see what code you've already tried and where you're having issues.

Comment: Please do not supply externally linked image. Instead, embed there here so they can't get lost.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you provided a good before -> after screenshot, there are still many uncertainties to me:

- What is the criteria when to group the part codes? Do L,W,T and Material have to be the same or are we simply appending all Part Codes and adding QTY?
- Is the input and output table the same? e.g. shall we delete rows or shall we print the output somewhere else?

The below code will create the desired output for the exact case you've shown, but I'm pretty sure that it is to simplistic for your true case (e.g. it currently only prints one line and adds everything to the first part code). Would be great if you could explain the above

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim rInput As Range
Dim vArr As Variant

Set rInput = Range("B5:G8")
vArr = rInput

For i = LBound(vArr) + 1 To UBound(vArr)
    If vArr(i, 3) = vArr(1, 3) And _
        vArr(i, 4) = vArr(1, 4) And _
        vArr(i, 5) = vArr(1, 5) And _
        vArr(i, 6) = vArr(1, 6) Then
            vArr(1, 1) = vArr(1, 1) & "," & vArr(i, 1)
            vArr(1, 2) = vArr(1, 2) + vArr(i, 2)
    End If
Next i

rInput.Offset(rInput.Rows.Count + 3).Resize(1, rInput.Columns.Count) = vArr

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for coming back so quickly. I would like the rows that are not needed to be deleted as the data will stay in the same table. The criteria required for the part codes to be combined is when L, W, T and Material is the same.